# what is the query language used in google-cloud-logging

Tags: google-cloud-logging

what is the query language used in google cloud logging? 
it doesn't seem to be lucene based?
For example, below is a query

```
metadata.serviceName="appengine.googleapis.com"
metadata.labels."appengine.googleapis.com/module_id"="..."
metadata.labels."appengine.googleapis.com/version_id"=",,,"
log="appengine.googleapis.com/stdout"
(error OR completed)
```

Answer (score 0):

Google seems to be using their own custom language for Stackdriver filters.

Syntax definition looks like this:

```
expression = ["NOT"] comparison { ("AND" | "OR") ["NOT"] comparison }

comparison = name OP value
           | value

OP = "<=" | "<" | ">=" | ">"  | "!=" | "=" | ":"

value = number
      | string
      | function
      | "(" expression ")"
```

You can find the rest of syntax definition here:

https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/advanced_filters#advanced_filter_syntax